# House power flicker

Tags: wiring, kitchens, stove

I just had a couple power flickers, power didnt quite come back fully. I was only getting 80 volts at my 120 outlets. The culprit seems to be my stove receptacle. I first checked voltage at the 200v receptacle and it wasnt right. I turned off the stoves breaker and i checked across each hot wire for continuity and my meter beeped. I then checked across each leg to ground and it also beeped on both. So, this receptacle is ringing str8 back to ground. What can this be?

Comment: Check more outlets. Are any giving *more than* 120V?

Comment: Does the oven/stove have a 3-wire or 4-wire connection?  i.e. Does it have separate neutral and ground?

Answer (score 1):

Anytime someone mentions flickering lights and strange voltages. I immediately think about a phase loss or broken neutral. So start by checking your voltage at the service feeder above your first means of disconnect and make sure you utility contractor hasn't lost a phase. If they have then contact them, but if it is ok then you need to start with your main overcurrent protection either fuse or breaker. Then disconnect the circuit from each breaker and check to see if the breaker has gone bad. You need to check all of the phase to phase voltages, voltage to neutral and phase to ground.

Good luck.

Comment: First thing that came to mind for me as well...